# Transforming a sum into an integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics, mathematics

I posted this in the mathematical forums. Maybe you will help me. I found an hard article [Link](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.105.776) of yang huang and luttinger. The authors begins with the sum: $$\frac{{E_2 }}{{E_0 }} = \frac{{16\pi ^2 a^2 \lambda ^2 }}{{V^2 }}\sum\limits_{} {'\frac{{\langle n_\alpha \rangle \langle n_\gamma \rangle \langle n_\lambda \rangle }}{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {k_\alpha ^2 + k_\beta ^2 - k_\gamma ^2 - k_\lambda ^2 } \right)}}\delta \left( {\vec k{}_\alpha + \vec k{}_\beta - \vec k{}_\gamma - \vec k{}_\lambda } \right)} $$ which represents the second order perturbation term of the energy of a bose gas. ${\langle n_\alpha \rangle }$ is: $$\langle n_\alpha \rangle = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty {n\left( {ze^{ - \beta \varepsilon _\alpha } } \right)} ^n /\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty {\left( {ze^{ - \beta \varepsilon _\alpha } } \right)} ^n = \frac{{ze^{ - \beta \varepsilon _\alpha } }}{{1 - ze^{ - \beta \varepsilon _\alpha } }} $$ In the sum the terms with a vanishing denominator are omitted. There is also the restriction ${\vec k{}_\alpha \ne \vec k{}_\beta }\ \ $ and ${\vec k{}_\gamma \ne \vec k{}_\lambda }\ \ $. Now the passage that is unclear to me is the passage to the integral: $$\frac{{E_2 }}{{E_0 }} = \frac{{16\pi a^2 \lambda ^2 }}{{V^2 }}\left( {\frac{{4V^3 }}{{\pi ^3 \lambda ^5 }}} \right)\sum\limits_{i,j,k}^\infty {\frac{{z^{j + k + l} }}{{\left( {j + k + l} \right)^{1/2} \left( {j - k} \right)l}}} \frac{{\partial J}}{{\partial u}} $$ where: $$J = \int\limits_0^\infty {\int\limits_0^\infty {dqdq\frac{{\cosh \left( {upq} \right)}}{{q^2 - p^2 }}} } e^{ - vq^2 - wp^2 } $$ and: $$u = \frac{{\hbar ^2 \beta }}{{2m}}\left( {\frac{{2\left( {j - k} \right)l}}{{j + k + l}}} \right) $$ $$v = \frac{{\hbar ^2 \beta }}{{2m}}\left( {\frac{{\left( {j + k} \right)l}}{{j + k + l}}} \right) $$ $$w = \frac{{\hbar ^2 \beta }}{{2m}}\left( {\frac{{\left( {j + k} \right)l + 4jk}}{{j + k + l}}} \right) $$ $\frac{{\partial J}}{{\partial u}}$ is calculated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63534/difficult-integral
Maybe we don't have to do thermal average of n and we need : $$n = \frac{1}{{z^{ - 1} e^{\varepsilon /kT} - 1}} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {\left( {ze^{ - \varepsilon /kT} } \right)^l } $$ so: $$\sum\limits_{} {'... = \sum\limits_{i,j,k = 1}^\infty {\sum\limits_{} ' } } z^{ijk} \frac{{e^{ - \frac{{\hbar ^2 k_a^2j }}{{2m}}} e^{ - \frac{{\hbar ^2 k_\gamma ^2k }}{{2m}}} e^{ - \frac{{\hbar ^2 k_\lambda ^2l }}{{2m}}} }}{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {k_a^2 + k_b^2 - k_\gamma ^2 - k_\lambda ^2 } \right)}} $$ This explain the factor $z^{ijk}$ and the sum. How can we continue?Now we have to transform the sum' in a integral. The density of state depends of $kdk$ so i think we have to evaluate: $$\int\limits_0^\infty {\frac{{e^{ - \frac{{\hbar ^2 k_a^2j }}{{2m}}} e^{ - \frac{{\hbar ^2 k_\gamma ^2k }}{{2m}}} e^{ - \frac{{\hbar ^2 k_\lambda ^2l }}{{2m}}} }}{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {k_a^2 + k_b^2 - k_\gamma ^2 - k_\lambda ^2 } \right)}}k_a k_b k_\gamma k_\lambda } dk_a dk_b dk_\gamma dk_\lambda $$ We have to evaluate two integrals, i think. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Presumably the authors have started by addressing the problem in a limited case with discrete states and then taken a limit in which the discrete states become a continuum. The classic example is quantizing the electromagnetic field in a perfectly conductive box and then taking the limit as the box grows without bound to get the quantization of the EM field in free space. Indeed, this appears to be a very similar procedure. This was discussed a little as [What's a good reference for this classical picture Feynman's talking about?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3554/520).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to solve this integral:
$$F\left( {a,b,c,d} \right) = \int {\frac{{e^{ - \frac{{\hbar ^2 }}{{2m}}\left( {ak_a^2  + bk_b^2  + ck_\gamma ^2  + dk_\lambda ^2 } \right)} }}{{\left( {k_a^2  + k_b^2  - k_\gamma ^2  - k_\lambda ^2 } \right)}}k_a k_b k_\gamma  k_\lambda  dk_a dk_b dk_\gamma  dk_\lambda  } 
$$
from which we can calculate our integral putting $b=0$. We have:
$$\frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial a}} + \frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial b}} - \frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial c}} - \frac{{\partial F}}{{\partial d}} \propto \frac{1}{{abcd}}
$$
Now we put:
$$i=a+b+c+d$$
$$l=a+b-c-d$$
$$m=a-b$$
$$n=c-d$$
So:
$$\frac{\partial }{{\partial a}} = \frac{\partial }{{\partial i}} + \frac{\partial }{{\partial l}} + \frac{\partial }{{\partial m}}
$$
$$\frac{\partial }{{\partial b}} = \frac{\partial }{{\partial i}} + \frac{\partial }{{\partial l}} - \frac{\partial }{{\partial m}}
$$
$$\frac{\partial }{{\partial c}} = \frac{\partial }{{\partial i}} - \frac{\partial }{{\partial l}} + \frac{\partial }{{\partial n}}
$$
$$\frac{\partial }{{\partial d}} = \frac{\partial }{{\partial i}} - \frac{\partial }{{\partial l}} - \frac{\partial }{{\partial n}}
$$
$$\frac{\partial }{{\partial a}} + \frac{\partial }{{\partial b}} - \frac{\partial }{{\partial c}} - \frac{\partial }{{\partial d}} = 4\frac{\partial }{{\partial l}}
$$
and:
$$a=(i+l+2m)/4$$
$$b=(i+l-2m)/4$$
$$c=(i-l+2n)/4$$
$$d=(i-l-2n)/4$$
and the equation becomes:
$$\frac{{\partial F'}}{{\partial l}} \propto \frac{1}{{\left( {\frac{{i + l}}{2} + m} \right)\left( {\frac{{i + l}}{2} - m} \right)\left( {\frac{{i - l}}{2} + n} \right)\left( {\frac{{i - l}}{2} - n} \right)}}
$$
The integration can be evaluated with derive, and the substitutions gives an expression divergent if we put $b=0$. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Think of $k_\alpha$ and $k_\beta$ as $x$ and $y$, so $dk_\alpha\;dk_\beta = dx\;dy.$ Now convert to polar coordinates = $rdr\;d\theta$. The integral over theta is trivial. Repeat with the other two wave vectors and you end up with two integrals.

Comment: Hey, do you want me to actually have to type the trivial calculation in? Herp derp.

Comment: Sorry i respond you soo late.Can you give me the calculations???

Comment: There's no calculation to type in. Simply replace $dk_\alpha\;dk_\beta = r\;dr\;d\theta$ where $k_\alpha$ and $k_\beta$ run from between + and - infinity, while r runs from 0 to infinity and theta runs from 0 to 2 pi. This is the usual Cartesian to polar conversion.

Comment: The result is very difficul to write, i don't think it's soo easy to get it. I tried to use polar coordinates but i don't know how to integrate!

Comment: Try using the substitution $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} H(k_\alpha,k_\beta)\;dk_\alpha\;dk_\beta$ $= \int_{r=0}^\infty\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}H(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))r\;d\theta \; dr$ $= \int_{r=0}^\infty\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}H(r) r\;d\theta \; dr$ $= 2\pi \int_{r=0}^\infty H(r)\;r \;dr$. This is a method of simplifying an integral of H that depends on the requirement that H simplify. It reduces two integrals down to 1. Also note that if the original integral of H was from 0 to infinity instead of -infinity to +infinity, then you have to make some simple changes.

Comment: I remember that the result is $$\frac{{E_2 }}{{E_0 }} = \frac{{16\pi a^2 \lambda ^2 }}{{V^2 }}\left( {\frac{{4V^3 }}{{\pi ^3 \lambda ^5 }}} \right)\sum\limits_{i,j,k}^\infty {\frac{{z^{j + k + l} }}{{\left( {j + k + l} \right)^{1/2} \left( {j - k} \right)l}}} \frac{{\partial J}}{{\partial u}} $$.  Your evaluation doens't take care of this complexity of the result. I don't think it's soo easy. I understand how to change to polar coordinates, i don't have problemas with this point. I don't think H is theta indipendent!

Comment: Re "I don't think H is theta independent." The algebra is pretty clear. Your H is a function of $k_\alpha^2+k_\beta^2$. But changing into polar coordinates, i.e. $r=\sqrt{k_\alpha^2+k_\beta^2}$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}(k_\beta/k_\alpha)$, gives you $k_\alpha^2+k_\beta^2 = (\sqrt{k_\alpha^2+k_\beta^2})^2 = r^2$ and there is no dependence on $\theta$.

Comment: The complexity comes from the complexity of $H$. But look at $H$ as if it were just a function of $k_\alpha$ and $k_\beta$. Solve that integral (i.e. reduce one dimension by using polar coordinates), and you'll get an answer which can be looked at as just a function of $k_\gamma$ and $k_\lambda$. Do the trick again with that integral and you will get the right answer. The algebra is not trivial but it is typical for what is expected of a physics grad student in a typical homework assignment.

Comment: Hi...there are several exponential in the numerator! When we trasform in polar coordinates they gives term like $cos^2(\theta)$

Comment: $k_\gamma^2+k_\lambda^2 = r^2$ so there is no theta dependence in the gamma / lambda to polar conversion. For the alpha and beta conversion, this is tough. What exactly happened to the delta function in the original equation at the top of your post? With things like that, one can manipulate stuff around so long as it changes the thing only away from the delta function.